# scala - performance time/memory between re-initialization and re-declaration of variables

Tags: performance, scala

Just out of curiosity, as the title suggests: is there any performance or memory allocation differences if the variables were declared and instantiated like this:

```
class someClass
  def showBoard(typeIs: String){
        if (typeIs == "animals"){
            val dir: File = new File("animals/");
            val blah1= ...;
            val blah3 = ...;
        }
        else if (typeIs == "sports"){
            //same variables
        }
        //same for other categories
```

rather than this:

```
class someClass
  var dir: File = null
  var blah = null
  var blah2 = null
  def showBoard(typeIs: String){
        if (typeIs == "animals"){
            dir = new File("animals/");
            blah = ...;
            blah2 = ...;
        }
        else if (typeIs == "sports"){
             //same variables
        }
        //same thing for the other categories
```

assuming the above code runs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no performance or memory diferences. But in terms of design and idiomatic scala code - mutable state is bad. Better use first one.

Comment: "no memory diferences.". Yes, there are. In the first case, the `val`s will be on the stack and so freed up  when `showBoard` terminates. In the second, they form part of the class and (in most cases) will end up on the heap - and only be freed when the object is. In some cases, this could be a performance impact too. The second is also not thread (or even recursive invocation) safe, too.

Comment: As I agree with the latter part of Murat's answer, I also agree with Paul's comment. Mutable state (var) is unsafe and the null instantiation could cause problems in the future. And the scope of the values also has to be taken into consideration. Nice insight, thanks guys! I had wrote the 1st scenario and the 2nd scenario was just hypothetical for this question.